# how to apply custom css property in extent report

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Using Extent Report Version 4,

There is provision in the report to add custom css,

Looking for correct syntax, By trying this both it is not applying :

```
 htmlReport.Config.CSS = "<styles>  <![CDATA[ .black-text { color: #fff !important; } ]]> </ styles>";

 htmlReport.Config.CSS = "<styles>  .black-text { color: #fff !important; }  </ styles>";
```

Comment: Omit any tags and only use css. Styles and CData isn't required. Start with .black-text.. also, there is a provision for this already, you can use text-white, text-black etc without any additional css.

Comment: Great, It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is,

```
htmlReport.Config.CSS = ".black-text { color: #fff !important; }";
```